# Unit testing in scala for httpUtils

Tags: scala, unit-testing, testing

```
def getDetails(userId: String, organization: String, url: String, model: String) = {
    httpUtils.get(userId, organization, url + "/models/" + model + "/modelsets").map {
      resp =>
        resp.status match {
          case Status.OK => parse(resp.body).extract[List[DatabaseDetails]]
          case _         => handleError(resp.status) //
        }
    }
  }
```

Can anybody help me in writing its unit test?

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking here. Do you want us to write source code for you?

Comment: actually i have to write the unit test program for this module using scalatest  and i don't how to start for this type of module